# Criar um patch a partir de um commit

Tags: git

Ao executar o comando `git apply` é possível criar um *commit* com alterações a partir de um arquivo de texto:

```
git apply ~/Downloads/patch.txt
```

Como faço para criar esse arquivo de *patch* a partir de um *commit* já existente?

Comment: Vou procurar aqui um pouco sobre `git format-patch`, que é o comando que eu uso para isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários da pergunta, basta usar o comando `git format-patch` segundo o manual do git, ele pode ser usado de várias formas, mas acredito que as principais são:

```
git format-patch <commitish_inicial>
```

ou

```
git format-patch <commitish_inicial>..<commitish_final>
```

Assim o `git` gera um ou mais arquivos no formato `0000-algo-como-a-msg-de-commit.patch` que podem ser aplicados com `git apply`.